# How to prevent "lock" on screen power-off in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, power-management, energy-saving, lock-screen

If my screen turns off due to power saving settings in Windows 8 the PC gets locked also. Is there a way to delay the locking another minute? I have no screen saver set (where the lock setting would be, but thats not even activated). I just want to reactivate the screen (e.g. in a meeting), without to log in every time the screen turns off.
I do want it to lock after a certain time.
The device is in a domain and synced with other devices, if that makes a difference.

Comment: This is handled by the screensaver settings just as it was handled in Windows 7.  If this is handled by a domain policy request it be adjusted.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't find the setting in Windows 8.1. Any idea how to do this in Windows 8.1? In 8.0, there was a setting in the Metro-style "Change PC settings" area.

Comment: The setting is in exactly the same place.